# Loading datasets in offline mode in sklearn and skmultilearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, skmultilearn

I would like to use datasets: emotions, scene, and yeast in my project in anaconda (python 3.6.5).
I have used the following codes:

> ```
> from skmultilearn.dataset import load_dataset
> X_train, y_train, feature_names, label_names = load_dataset('emotions', 'train')
> ```

It works successfully when I am connected to the internet, 
But when I am offline, it doesn't work!
I have downloaded all 3 named above datasets in a folder like this:

> H:\Projects\Datasets

How can I use this folder as my source datasets while I am offline?
(I'm using windows 10)

The extensions of datasets that I have downloaded them are: .rar
Like this: emotions.rar, scene.rar, and yeast.rar, and I have downloaded them from: http://mulan.sourceforge.net/datasets-mlc.html

Comment: when using `load_dataset()` you are attempting to download certain datasets from a server, which is not possible without an internet connection. If you already have the files downloaded in local storage, you might be able to use them in the [offline mode](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/overview/#online-and-offline-modes) by using other file utilities (like importing a `csv` file to a pandas dataframe)

Comment: Is there any solution that I use my computer as local server to load dataset from my HDD with function `load_dataset()` ?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: Your answer was useful to find what is my problem.
But to solve my problem, I used @makis solution.
Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but you first need to know the path that the dataset was stored to.
To do this you can load once and get the path. This path will never change so you only need to do the following once in order to get the desired path. Next, knowing the path, you can load offline whatever you want.

**Example**:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd, os

#get the path
path = load_iris()['filename']
print(path)

#offline load
df = pd.read_csv(path)

#the path: THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED
main_path_with_datasets = os.path.dirname(path)
```

Once you get the `main_path_with_datasets` i.e. by doing `main_path_with_datasets = os.path.dirname(path)`, you will now have the path. You can use it to load all the available downloaded datasets.

```
os.listdir(main_path_with_datasets)

['digits.csv.gz',
 'wine_data.csv',
 'diabetes_target.csv.gz',
 'iris.csv',
 'breast_cancer.csv',
 'diabetes_data.csv.gz',
 'linnerud_physiological.csv',
 'linnerud_exercise.csv',
 'boston_house_prices.csv']
```

**EDIT for skmultilearn**

```
from skmultilearn.dataset import load_dataset_dump

path = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\scikit_ml_learn_data\\'

X, y, feature_names, label_names = load_dataset_dump(path + 'emotions-train.scikitml.bz2')
```

Comment: The datasets was downloaded in this folder automatically:
`C:\Users\myname\scikit_ml_learn_data`
And it's name is: `emotions-train.scikitml.bz2`

But it seems that my program doesn't use it! because every time that I run my program, it checks that internet connection. If there is no connection, the program doesn't work!

Comment: then you just need `os.listdir("C:\Users\myname\scikit_ml_learn_data")`

Comment: Your last answer seems that works with some little edit like this: `path = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\scikit_ml_learn_data\\'`.
I'll check it and I'll tell you.
Thank you.

Comment: right. If you have WINDOWS you need double backslash

Comment: nice. consider upvoting my answer